# Return empty collection when this collection is lazy intitialized

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

I have this object:

**Entity**

```
@Entity
public class someClass{
    private String name;
    private String labelKey;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**DTO**

```
public class someClass{
    private String name;
    private String labelKey;
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
}
```

My problem is that when I get this object but products are lazy initialized, when I mapp entity to DTO using Dozer, I get a LaziInitializedException, then i want to get that when I get products lazy initialized, this products will return a empry Set.
Is this possible?

Thanks for your time and sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this tutorial [here](https://www.baeldung.com/dozer#Mapping) you can instruct `dozer` to exclude some field from the mapping.

If you do so, then the dozer will not invoke the method of `getProducts` of your entity class and therefore the exception `LaziInitializedException` will not be thrown.

At the same time because your DTO object is initialized with an empty `HashSet` for the field products, this is what will remain at the end in the DTO.

So your requirement will work, where your entity is lazily initialized for products and your DTO returns an empty list while at the same time the mapping happens from `dozer`.

Here is the configuration that you need for the mapper of `dozer`.

```
BeanMappingBuilder mappingExclusion = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        mapping(SomeClassEntity.class, SomeClassDto.class).exclude("products");
    }
};
mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
mapper.addMapping(mappingExclusion);
```

Then you can use it to do the mapping as following

```
mapper.map(someClassEntityInstance, someClassDtoInstance);
```

Comment: Yes, it's work, now I have created two mappers, one of them excluding the subProducts field and the other incliding it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create/modify your Getter such that:

```
public Set<Product> getProducts() {
   if (products == null) {
       return new HashSet<>();
       //or products = new HashSet<>(), but I'm not sure of the side effects as far as database framework is concerned.
   }
   return products;
}
```

Comment: Hi, to begin thanks for your answer, but in this case I don't know if hibernate would do the transaccion in background searching the products, also I think this solution doesn't avoid the LazyInitializationException.

Answer (score 0):

Try marking your service class or method as @Transactional to let Spring handle session management.

```
public class ServiceUsingSomeClass {
    final SomeClassRepository someClassRepository;

    //Constructor ...
    
    @Transactional
    showProducts() {
       someClassRepository.findAll();
       // Do something with Set<Product>

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to avoid fetching the association in cases where you use Dozer for DTO mapping, you could configure it to ignore `products` field in source object by extending `DozerConverter` and using that custom converter.

I also feel that maybe that means your target type doesn't really need to have
a `products` field to begin with, since you're not going to populate it.

If there's many places like this in your codebase, consider using projections to only fetch the properties necessary for the purpose at hand.

@fella7ena brings up a point about @Transactional, however this is actually unrelated - you can still come across LazyInitializationException within a transaction. This happens because Hibernate loses track of the relation between the java bean's persistence state and the database state. If you actually wanted to fetch `products` association from the database, you would have to use eager fetchtype (leads to n+1 issue), batching, or entitygraphs.

Comment: Hi, to begin thanks for your answer, but en some cases I want to mapper products attribute and in others not, I am trying to find out some method to if products have been lazy initialized, then or create a empty hashMap or put null in the products or find out some way to avoid the exception.

Comment: In that case I strongly recommend using projections as you probably won’t be able to alter hibernate proxy behavior.  You could use a custom DozerConverter to catch LazyInitializationException in principle, but personally I wouldn’t like using exceptions for what is normal course of events